# Creating Objects where multiple objects have the same properties

Tags: c#

My program is starting to get pretty big. and i have found that its starting to do the same thing in multiple area's.
Im trying to figure out how i can make it more efficient.

So i have an object that looks like this

```
    public class TreeViewNode
    {
        public TreeViewNode()
        {
            Children = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewNode>();
        }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<TreeViewNode> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

i also have another object that looks like this;

```
public class ComputerObject
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Int32 UUID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Object> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Both these items need to have some of the same properties..
at the moment they both have the Children Property and the Name Property. but they both need to have some other common properties added to them.

so i have tried something like this.

```
    public class BaseObject
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Object> Children { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public BaseObject()
        {
            Children = new ObservableCollection<object>();
        }
    }
    public class ComputerObject: BaseObject
    {
        public Int32 UUID { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }            
    }
    public class TreeViewNode: BaseObject
    {
        public String IconPath { get; set; }

    }
```

Now this is just a cut down version of what i am implementing, i have alot of objects that share the same properties. and some that dont and mix and match. and i cannot figure out the best implimentation for this.

My Objects are becoming very cluttered, and when i rename a property i find that i have to rename it in several area's and this isnt the way its ment to be.

can someone please advise how i would implement multiple objects that share the same property names?

Comment: Do they have the same properties by coincidence? Or because they share some usage? This matters. Personally, I would say "prefer interfaces over inheritance", but frankly I'm not sure that there is any reason to want to share anything between these objects. They look to be unrelated.

Comment: Do they have any relationship between them other than having same properties? for example Cat, Dog are amimals. Does these classes have some relationship like this?

Comment: Perhaps you are asking for the so-called Mixin pattern, which cannot be implemented directly in C#: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin

Comment: Yes they share the same value's forexample. i have a remote desktop usercontrol and network shares control. these both have a class that contains things like, Name / IP Address / Logged on user.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into decorator pattern. In short, you dont share common properties via inheritance. You make classes that contain common properties, and use these classes as properties in your end classes.

**EDIT: Example is actually just a standard composition, it should work nevertheless**

E.G.

```
public class Decorator1
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Object> Children { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Decorator2
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
}

public class ClassA
{
    public Decorator1 TreeNodeImpl;
}

public class ClassB
{
    public Decorator1 TreeNodeImpl;
    public Decorator2 LongIdImpl;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this just standard composition?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should not let classes inherit  from one baseclass when these childclasses are not related to each other (like @Sriram Sakthivel asked Animal < Dog,Cat) just to share the same properties.

You should determine which classes are related (cat, dog are animals; car, motorcycle are vehicles) and then create baseclasses based on these "groupings".